q parameter in files.list returns invalid value error
I trying to get a list of files in Google Drive using q parameter in files.list() method, but my queries throw an error:

'Invalid value' in q parameter.

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint 

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_HIDDEN_FILE
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

USER_ID = 12275235249402556851
USER_ID = str(USER_ID)

Query = ' owners has {permissionId=' + USER_ID + ' }'
listOfFiles = service.files().list(
    q = Query,
    fields='files(id, owners(emailAddress), modifiedTime, ownedByMe)').execute()
pp.pprint(listOfFiles)

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-filesMy Google Drive contains 10 folders and files, so i don't need nextPageToken (for now). I tried an easy query like 'ownedByMe' = False but still get valueError:
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%22ownedByMe%22+%3D+False&fields=files%28id%2C+owners%28permissionId%29%2C+modifiedTime%2C+ownedByMe%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value". Details: "[{'message': 'Invalid Value', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'q', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">

I tried different options to write easy query like this:
ownedByMe = False
ownedByMe = fale
'ownedByMe' = 'False'
False in ownedByMe
ownedByMe has False

But still get value Error. I looking for solution on search files guide, but it doesn't help

The query is literally owners has {"permissionId" = " + str(USER_ID) + "}, which I don't think you wanted.

Maybe you meant 'owners has {"permissionId"="' + str(USER_ID) + '"}' instead?

My bad, actually it  'owners has {"permissionId" =' + USER_ID + '}'. I edited my question.

Looking at their examples, I don't think permissionId is supposed to be in double quotes.  properties has { key='mass' and value='1.3kg' }

Yes, i tried Querry = Querry = ' owners has {permissionId=' + USER_ID + ' }`, but still get ValueError

What do you want to do at Querry = ' owners has {permissionId=' + USER_ID + ' }'?
